# add libusb lib and include to my crosscompiler

Tags: cross-compiling, libusb

my suse linux have arm-cross compiler installed and worked well. 
now we tried to compile a file which use libusb functions. the linker complain can't find some files.
I know it's because I have no libusb for my arm-cross compiler. I get latest libusb source code from here
https://github.com/libusb/libusb/releases
but get stuck. how to build it? and how to put the lib/ and include/ etc to my toolchain. so as linker could find missing files?
read others post, say there is ./configure  in the package. I did not find it.
please help. it so confuse. libusb official web, don't have instruction of how to build libusb from source.

thanks
Xian

Comment: in that link I download source code(tar.gz) which don't have ./configure. I then download libusb-1.0.22.tar.bz2 . it contains ./configure. now I could continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to add headers and .so files via -I and -L options of GCC.

Since you're cross compiling, it would be right to specify installation folder to separate directory (not to host one by default), `make install` and use files from there via -I and -L options.

Alternatively you can set installation path to GCC sysroot folder (check it with gcc --print-sysroot).